# Why can't I have my own custom root directive in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, centos

**OS:** Centos7

**Nginx:** 1.9.14

Please consider this simple server block

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have scoured the net trying to figure this one out. The above configuration works. Located at the root directive is a file called index.php and contains this line

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

### Navigating to the site reveals PHPINFO. So this confirms that PHP is working correctly however..

**Let's say I want to change my root directive to;**

```
root /steven/html;
```

Inside this location the same index.php file resides. But instead of PHPINFO I get;

```
File not found.
```

All I did was change the root directive, because that is where I'd rather put my files..  The **/var/log/nginx/error.log** reveals;

```
2016/05/24 04:03:41 [error] 473#473: *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 125.238.2.111, server: website.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "website.com"
```

- Folder permissions for /usr/share/nginx/html are all root:root 755
- Folder permissions for /steven/html are also root:root 755

#### Anyone got an idea why? I would really appreciate an eye opener here.

I know the following will be asked so I will include these.

**Nginx compiled from source**

```
nginx version: nginx/1.9.14
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --add-module=/root/custom-nginx/nginx-1.9.14/src/http/modules/ngx_cache_purge/ --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-threads --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_v2_module --without-mail_pop3_module --without-mail_imap_module --without-mail_smtp_module --without-http_uwsgi_module --without-http_scgi_module --without-http_memcached_module --with-openssl=../../openssl-1.0.2g --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic'
```

**Contents of fastcgi_params**

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

**Sanity check**

```
[root@ip-172-31-2-48 /]# ls -l /steven/html
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 17 May 24 03:49 index.php
```

Comment: Presume you restarted nginx after changes (`sudo service nginx restart`) - just to be certain? Also 100% certain that location exists? - `ls -l /steven/html` returns what?

Comment: Of course :) 2 whole days of it.

Comment: I've added the output to the end of the question

Comment: Can you check these 2 things and get back to me; (1) Nothing else running on port `9000` (*maybe switch it to `9001` and try see if it works*). (2) Switch the following lines `include fastcgi_params;` & `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` around then restart and try

Answer (score 1):

It isn't very often I get to answer my own question with a resounding YES!

@Darren asked me to change the listening port for PHP-FPM from it's default 9000 to something else.

I tried to do this but for some reason the php-fpm.service wouldn't allow it. Oh dear..

```
ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '127.0.0.1:9001': Permission denied (13)
```

I found this.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180460/php-fpm-error-unable-to-bind-listening-socket-for-address-127-0-0-19003-perm

```
cat /etc/selinux/config
```

Change **SELINUX=enforcing** to **SELINUX=disabled**

Not only did this allow the port number for the PHP-FPM process to bind to 9001, but it also fixed the file not found issue when I wanted to specify my own root directive.

### Perhaps someone would know how to create a SELINUX rule to allow this instead of disabling it altogether.

Now it is possible that all the people having issues with **File not found** - this is what you need to check.

Thanks again to @Darren, however I would never had discovered this.

Comment: Ah there you go! Would've never picked the issue to be that!